# Как десериализировать json с помощью ObjectMapper в класс реализующий Map

Tags: java, json, jackson

Класс, объект которого я должен десериализовать, наследуется от HashMap. При десериализации весь json записывается в мапу, и вместо желаемого

```
MyClass{
{}
String field1 = "field"
int field2 = number
}
```

я получаю

```
MyClass{
{field1 = field, field2 = number}
String field1 = null
int field2 = 0
}
```

десериализация реализована так :

```
MyClass myClass = objectMapper.readValue(CONSTANT, MyClass.class);
```

константа:

```
CONSTANT = "{\"field1\": \"field\",\"field2\":number}";
```

MyClass:

```
MyClass extends HashMap<K, V>{
@JsonProperty("field1")
String field1;
@JsonProperty("field2")
int field2;
}
```

я не могу вносить какие либо изменения в MyClass. Подскажите, что делать?